# Javascript reverse verify input code?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that checks if a certain 4 number code is put in :

```
verify = function (num, success) {

    if (true && (num & Math.pow(2, 0)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 1)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 2)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 3)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 4)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 5)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 6)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 7)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 8)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 9)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 10)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 11)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 12)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 13)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 14)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 15)) == 0) {
        setTimeout(success, 1000);
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }

}
```

How do i reverse this to find out what number it wants ?
No worries, its for a hacking game at my work :)

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: Ew, `Math.pow`... Just use `2<<0`, `2<<1`, `2<<2`...

Answer (score 3):

Just do the math. The code is an extremely ugly way to create a bitmask:

0b0001110010001010 is the target number, which is 7306.

EDIT: Then again, the code would accept 0b10001110010001010 too, which is 72842. Any number with the specified lower 15 bits is acceptable to this algorithm.

Comment: Hmm, thanks in advance everybody! But it wont accept the code ..
Maybe because it wants something else ? http://pastebin.com/C97H7zzq
The echo(decrypt part is what you see above .. I'm trying to solve it but understand it at the same time.. Im a java noob but for some reason i can't let this one go .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take all the mathematical operations and reverse them, taking care to keep the order of operations correct.

Note though that in some cases there are trapdoor algorithms that have multiple potential inputs for one output. In that case it is actually impossible to reverse them, although you can still find a potential solution.