# Getting binary number out of code

Tags: javascript

I have seen this question earlier, but i did not understand the answer.

```
function (num, success) {
    if (true  && (num & Math.pow(2, 0)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 1)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 2)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 3)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 4)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 5)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 6)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 7)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 8)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 9)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 10)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 11)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 12)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 13)) != 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 14)) == 0 && (num & Math.pow(2, 15)) == 0)
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get the binary value out of this code?

So I can proceed to turn it into a 4-digit number.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  What "earlier question" are you referring to?  What "binary value" do you see here?  This isn't even valid code!

Comment: I've seen this before. It's an obfuscated number test.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Care to elaborate?  I'm intrigued!

Comment: this is just testing if the "i"th digit is null or not but this is not returning any binary number !

Comment: `num = Math.pow(2, 0) + Math.pow(2, 1) + Math.pow(2, 3) + Math.pow(2, 4) + Math.pow(2, 7) + Math.pow(2, 9) + Math.pow(2, 10) + Math.pow(2, 13)` or the bit tests won't pass.

Comment: The question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678483/javascript-reverse-verify-input-code

Answer (score 1):

That's just a code snippet, not a full function, as you're not returning anything and this is just a conditional in the if statement, however, the spirit of the question is how can you get a binary number from that conditional. So...

First you need to understand what the `Math.pow` function does.`Math.pow(2,0)` will yield the number 1, because that is 2 to the power of 0, or 2^0. `Math.pow(2,1)` is 2, `Math.pow(2,2)` is 4 and so on.

Ok, so how do you know a binary number? Binary 101 is the number 5, because it is `1*(2^2) + 0*(2^1) + 1*(2^0)`. So look at the conditional:

`num & Math.pow(2,0)` will be either one or zero. So you compare it with `==` and `!=` to find out, and use the `AND` operator (`&&`) to make sure it's comparing the true/false results. In the example above of 101, you'd need true as a result of the following conditional:

`(num & Math.pow(2, 2)) != 0`    ---> meaning 1

`&&`

`(num & Math.pow(2, 1)) == 0`   ---> meaning 0

`&&`

`(num & Math.pow(2, 0)) != 0`   ---> meaning 1

Comment: I understand the issue now.

Comment: Np, I'm glad to help. Thanks for the edit, it does look clearer this way.